# Joining three tables to get summary data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new-moderate at SQL and have an issue which I believe can be done with a few SQL queries ... if I understood Joins better.

I have three tables, each linked via primary/foreign keys to the other.
The reality is there are about 60,000 records in the deepest table, but for simplicity you can recreate my table structure with this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FileData (fd_ID_pk INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Analyst VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO FileData (Analyst) VALUES('AD'), ('LS'), ('MM'), ('MM'), ('MM'), ('LS'), ('LS'), ('AD'), ('MM');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IndData (sp_ID_pk INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, fd_ID_fk INT NOT NULL, IndNum INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (fd_ID_fk) REFERENCES FileData (fd_ID_pk));
INSERT INTO IndData (fd_ID_fk, IndNum) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (2,7), (2,8), (2,9), (2,10), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (3,7), (3,8), (3,9), (3,10), (3,11), (3,12), (3,13), (3,14), (3,15), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5), (4,6), (4,7), (4,8),  (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5), (6,6), (6,7), (7,1), (7,2), (7,3), (7,4), (7,5), (7,6), (7,7), (8,1), (8,2), (8,3), (8,4), (8,5), (8,6), (8,7), (8,8), (9,1), (9,2), (9,3), (9,4), (9,5);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FinData (sp_1_fk INT NULL, sp_2_fk INT NULL, sp_3_fk INT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (sp_1_fk) REFERENCES IndData (sp_ID_pk), FOREIGN KEY (sp_2_fk) REFERENCES IndData (sp_ID_pk), FOREIGN KEY (sp_3_fk) REFERENCES IndData (sp_ID_pk));
INSERT INTO FinData (sp_1_fk, sp_2_fk, sp_3_fk) VALUES (57,null,64), (18,64,67), (null,11,35), (null,58,35), (null,null,24), (18,null,null), (null, 6,26), (34,null, 8), (null, 8,null), (59,68,28), (null, 1,17), (39,55,null), (65,58, 7), (null,null,10), (54, 6,null), (53,null,67), (27,19,41), (null,57, 5), ( 6,31,17),( 4,64,25), (38,13,58), (55,null, 2), (66,null, 4), (10,10,null), (40,61,46), (null,null,52), ( null,39,46), (null,11,32), (12,null,39), (56,44,21),(22,25,53), (37,null,null), (12,null,49), (43, null,13), (19,17,26), (46, 9,44), (null,13,null), (53,null, 6), (32,30,null)
```

Basically, the first table is a list of files and each file has an analyst associated with it.  There can be more than one file per analyst.

```
fd_ID_pk   Analyst
1         AD
2         LS
3         MM
4         MM
etc
```

The second table is a list of data entries from that file, each record has a key.

```
sp_ID_pk   fd_ID_fk   IndNum
1          1          1
2          1          2
3          1          3
4          1          4
5          1          5
6          1          6
7          2          1
8          2          2
etc
```

The third table is where it gets complicated for me.  This has three columns each of which is linked to a record in the second table, which can be null

```
sp_1_fk   sp_2_fk   sp_3_fk
12                  39
56        44        21
22        25        53
37                      
12                  49
43                  13
19        17        26
```

What I need is a summary table that shows the counts of files and IndData and FinData for each analyst.

I've gotten this which gives me the total counts per analyst, but they don't seem right at all:

```
SELECT filedata.Analyst, COUNT(filedata.Analyst) as 'count'
FROM filedata
JOIN inddata
ON filedata.fd_ID_pk = inddata.fd_ID_fk
JOIN findata
ON findata.sp_1_fk = inddata.sp_ID_pk OR findata.sp_2_fk = inddata.sp_ID_pk OR findata.sp_3_fk = inddata.sp_ID_pk
GROUP BY filedata.Analyst
```

Ideally, however, I'm trying to get this:

```
Analyst   TotalFiles   FilesUsed   TotalInd   IndUsed
AD        2            2           14         10        
LS        3            3           24         16
MM        4            4           32         24
```

with some queries ... any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

first try to get result joining table 3 and 2

```
SELECT ID.sp_ID_pk, COUNT(*) AS VAL , COUNT(distinct IndNum) AS IDUSED
  FROM IndData ID 
  LEFT JOIN FinData FD ON FD.sp_1_fk = ID.sp_ID_pk 
  LEFT JOIN FinData FDD ON FDD.sp_2_fk = ID.sp_ID_pk 
  LEFT JOIN FinData FDDD ON FDDD.sp_3_f k= ID.sp_ID_pk 
GROUP BY ID.sp_ID_pk;



 +----------+-----+--------+
    | sp_ID_pk | VAL | IDUSED |
    +----------+-----+--------+
    |        1 |   1 |      1 |
    |        2 |   1 |      1 |
    |        3 |   1 |      1 |
    |        4 |   1 |      1 |
    |        5 |   1 |      1 |
    |        6 |   2 |      1 |
    |        7 |   1 |      1 |
    |        8 |   1 |      1 |
    |        9 |   1 |      1 |
    |       10 |   1 |      1 |
    |       11 |   2 |      1 |
    |       12 |   2 |      1 |
    |       13 |   2 |      1 |
    |       14 |   1 |      1 |
    |       15 |   1 |      1 |
    |       16 |   1 |      1 |
    |       17 |   2 |      1 |
    |       18 |   2 |      1 |
    |       19 |   1 |      1 |
    |       20 |   1 |      1 |
    |       21 |   1 |      1 |
    |       22 |   1 |      1 |
    |       23 |   1 |      1 |
    |       24 |   1 |      1 |
    |       25 |   1 |      1 |
    |       26 |   2 |      1 |
    |       27 |   1 |      1 |
    |       28 |   1 |      1 |
    |       29 |   1 |      1 |
    |       30 |   1 |      1 |
    |       31 |   1 |      1 |
    |       32 |   1 |      1 |
    |       33 |   1 |      1 |
    |       34 |   1 |      1 |
    |       35 |   2 |      1 |
    |       36 |   1 |      1 |
    |       37 |   1 |      1 |
    |       38 |   1 |      1 |
    |       39 |   1 |      1 |
    |       40 |   1 |      1 |
    |       41 |   1 |      1 |
    |       42 |   1 |      1 |
    |       43 |   1 |      1 |
    |       44 |   1 |      1 |
    |       45 |   1 |      1 |
    |       46 |   2 |      1 |
    |       47 |   1 |      1 |
    |       48 |   1 |      1 |
    |       49 |   1 |      1 |
    |       50 |   1 |      1 |
    |       51 |   1 |      1 |
    |       52 |   1 |      1 |
    |       53 |   2 |      1 |
    |       54 |   1 |      1 |
    |       55 |   1 |      1 |
    |       56 |   1 |      1 |
    |       57 |   1 |      1 |
    |       58 |   2 |      1 |
    |       59 |   1 |      1 |
    |       60 |   1 |      1 |
    |       61 |   1 |      1 |
    |       62 |   1 |      1 |
    |       63 |   1 |      1 |
    |       64 |   2 |      1 |
    |       65 |   1 |      1 |
    |       66 |   1 |      1 |
    |       67 |   2 |      1 |
    |       68 |   1 |      1 |
    |       69 |   1 |      1 |
    |       70 |   1 |      1 |
    +----------+-----+--------+
    70 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

then join it with below table

```
mysql> select * from FileData;
+----------+---------+
| fd_ID_pk | Analyst |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | AD      |
|        2 | LS      |
|        3 | MM      |
|        4 | MM      |
|        5 | MM      |
|        6 | LS      |
|        7 | LS      |
|        8 | AD      |
|        9 | MM      |
+----------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Whenever multiple 1-to-many relations are involved in a query, most aggregates will need calculated in subqueries to prevent the different "many"'s from multiplying the pre-aggregated result count.