# MySQL Data Summary/Counts Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put together a summary table that has counts of types of mail sent by group.

Hopefully the below is enough to explain what I mean.

Table 1 (senders)

```
| id | name | group_id |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | mike | 1        |
| 2  | john | 1        |
| 3  | lucy | 2        |
| 4  | lobo | 3        |
```

Table 2 (mail)

```
| id | type     | sender_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | letter   | 1         |
| 2  | postcard | 2         |
| 3  | postcard | 1         |
| 4  | letter   | 2         |
| 5  | postcard | 2         |
| 6  | postcard | 4         |
```

Table 3 (groups)

```
| id | name  | active |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | alpha | 1      |
| 2  | black | 1      |
| 3  | cero  | 0      |
```

Ideal result

```
| group | letter | postcard | parcel |
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
| alpha | 2      | 3        | 0      |
| black | 0      | 0        | 0      |
```

So I need to get counts per mail type for active groups.

I've been working through examples (only learning MySQL) but when I think of this situation I'm just totally blank.

Have looked at the answers to [Joining three tables to get summary data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149956/joining-three-tables-to-get-summary-data-in-mysql) but I don't quite understand how to translate the answers to my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You put this query

```
Select count(*) from senders s inner join mail m on s.id = s.sender_id inner join
groups g on s.groups_id = g.id group by m.type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name,
 MAX(CASE t.TYPE WHEN 'letter' THEN @CS:=@CS+1 ELSE 0 END ) letter,
 MAX(CASE t.TYPE WHEN 'postcard' THEN @CS1:=@CS1+1 ELSE 0 END ) postcard ,
 MAX(CASE t.TYPE WHEN 'parcel ' THEN @CS2:=@CS2+1 ELSE 0 END ) parcel  
FROM 
(SELECT
    groups. name,
    mail.type
FROM
    groups
LEFT JOIN senders ON groups.id = senders.id
LEFT JOIN mail ON senders.id = mail.sender_id ) AS t
,(SELECT @CS:=0) CS ,(SELECT @CS1:=0) CS1 ,(SELECT @CS2:=0) CS2
```

Comment: add some explanation